# Jlist and JScrollPane

Tags: java, eclipse

Can someone please tell me how to add a JScrollPane to a Jlist without using a flowlayout and how to add it to a JFrame?

This is what I have :

```
    list = new JList(songNames);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(3);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.setLocation(120, 120);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `FlowLayout` but you should certainly use a layout manager. The use of `setLocation` use seem to suggest that you are using a absolute positioning (`null` layout).

In that case the `JScrollPane` will have a default size of `0 x 0` and not appear. Instead use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Then simply adding the `panel` component to the `JFrame` will make both the `JScrollPane` and `JList` appear.